# Как нарисовать картинку текстом в стиле ASCII-art?

Tags: java, алгоритм, изображения, консоль, символы

Пытаюсь нарисовать картинку текстом, в стиле ASCII-art. Пиксели в символы отображаю так: для каждого пикселя получаю среднее значение яркости `(R+G+B)/3` и по значению яркости получаю символ соответствующей *плотности*. Имеется следующий код, но здесь некорректно составлена шкала плотностей символов. Символы распределены неравномерно. На выходе получается повернутое изображение, надо поменять местами `width` и `height`.

Как правильно создать шкалу плотностей символов? Или каким способом лучше отображать пиксель в символ?

```java
private static BufferedImage image;
private static int width, height;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  readImage("image.png");
  writeToFile("image.txt", getBrightness());
}

static void readImage(String path) throws IOException {
  File imageFile = new File(path);
  image = ImageIO.read(imageFile);
  width = image.getWidth();
  height = image.getHeight();
}

static void writeToFile(String path, int[][] brightness) throws IOException {
  File textFile = new File(path);
  FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(textFile);
  for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
      writer.append(getDensity(brightness[i][j]));
    }
    writer.write("\n");
  }
}

static int[][] getBrightness() {
  // массив яркостей пикселей картинки
  int[][] brightness = new int[width][height];

  for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
      Color c = new Color(image.getRGB(i, j));
      // получаем яркость как среднее значение (красный + зеленый + синий) / 3
      brightness[i][j] = (c.getRed() + c.getGreen() + c.getBlue()) / 3;
    }
  }
  return brightness;
}

private static final String DENSITY =
"\"`^\\\",:;Il!i~+_-?][}{1)(|\\\\/tfjrxnuvczXYUJCLQ0OZmwqpdbkhao*#MW&8%B@$\"";

static char getDensity(int value) {
  // получаем символ 'char' по процентному значению яркости
  // поскольку у нас нет 255 символов, будем использовать проценты
  double percent = DENSITY.length() / 255.0;
  int charValue = (int)(Math.round(percent * value));
  if (charValue < 0) {
    charValue = 0;
  } else if (charValue >= DENSITY.length()) {
    charValue = DENSITY.length() - 1;
  }
  return DENSITY.charAt(charValue);
}
```

Comment: скажите, а зачем вы удаляете и пишете заново одни и те же ответы (не только к этому вопросу, и явно не только из-под этой учётной записи)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Создаём карты плотности символов и яркости пикселей

Можно создать собственную *карту плотности символов `TreeMap`* из любого диапазона `UTF-16`. Для этого потребуется *моноширинный* шрифт для символов этого диапазона. Символы разных диапазонов имеют разные размеры. Затем, поскольку плотности символов почти в любом диапазоне распределены неравномерно, то на основе процента плотности символов можно получить *карту яркости пикселей `TreeMap`*, чтобы проще можно было получать *ближний* к нужному значению символ, вызывая методы [`ceilingEntry`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#ceilingEntry(K)) и/или [`floorEntry`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#floorEntry(K)).

Сначала нарисуем каждый символ как чёрно-белое изображение с помощью классов пакета `java.awt` и подсчитаем количество пикселей - получим *карту плотности символов*. Затем для каждой записи этой карты подсчитаем процент яркости по шкале `[0-255]` - получим *карту яркости пикселей*.

Изображения:

| Исходное изображение | ASCII: 0 - 255 0x0000 - 0x00FF | Руны: 0x16A0 - 0x16FF | Рамки: 0x2500 - 0x257F | Блоки: 0x2580 - 0x259F | Геом. фигуры: 0x25A0 - 0x25FF | Hiragana: 0x3040 - 0x309F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [image: enter link description here] | [image] | [image] | [image] | [image] | [image] | [image] |

Шкалы плотности символов:

| Блок Юникода | Диапазон символов | Шкала плотности |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ASCII | ``` 0-255 ``` | ``` ¶@ØÆMåBNÊßÔR#8Q&mÃ0À$GXZA5ñk2S%±3Fz¢yÝCJf1t7ªLc¿+?(r/¤²!*;"^:,'.` ``` |
| [Руны](https://unicode-table.com/ru/blocks/runic/) | ``` 0x16A0-0x16FF ``` | ``` ᛥᛤᛞᚥᚸᛰᛖᚻᚣᛄᚤᛒᚢᚱᛱᚷᚫᛪᚧᚬᚠᛏᚨᚰᚩᚮᚪᚳᚽᚿᛊᛁᛵᛍ᛬ᚲᛌ᛫ ``` |
| [Рамки](https://unicode-table.com/ru/blocks/box-drawing/) | ``` 0x2500-0x257F ``` | ``` ╬╠╫╋║╉╩┣╦╂╳╇╈┠╚┃╃┻╅┳┡┢┹╀╧┱╙┗┞┇┸┋┯┰┖╲╱┎╘━┭┕┍┅╾│┬┉╰╭╸└┆╺┊─╌┄┈╴╶ ``` |
| [Блоки](https://unicode-table.com/ru/blocks/block-elements/) | ``` 0x2580-0x259F ``` | ``` █▉▇▓▊▆▅▌▚▞▀▒▐▍▃▖▂░▁▏ ``` |
| [Геометрические фигуры](https://unicode-table.com/ru/blocks/geometric-shapes/) | ``` 0x25A0-0x25FF ``` | ``` ◙◘■▩●▦▣◚◛◕▨▧◉▤◐◒▮◍◑▼▪◤▬◗◭◖◈◎◮◊◫▰◄◯□▯▷▫▽◹△◁▸▭◅▵◌▱▹▿◠◃◦◟◞◜ ``` |
| [Хирагана](https://unicode-table.com/ru/blocks/hiragana/) | ``` 0x3040-0x309F ``` | ``` ぽぼゑぜぬあおゆぎゐはせぢがきぱびほげばゟぁたかぞぷれひずどらさでけぉちごえすゎにづぇとょついこぐうぅぃくっしへゞゝ゚゙ ``` |

Код:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
  // шрифт для отображения текста
  Font font = new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 22);
  // ASCII: 0 - 255
  // Руны: 0x16A0 - 0x16FF
  // Рамки: 0x2500 - 0x257F
  // Блоки: 0x2580 - 0x259F
  // Геометрические фигуры: 0x25A0 - 0x25FF
  // Хирагана: 0x3040 - 0x309F
  // карта плотности символов
  TreeMap<Integer, List<String>> density = getDensityMap(font,0x25A0,0x25FF,0);
  // карта яркости пикселей [0, 255]
  TreeMap<Integer, List<String>> brightness = getBrightnessMap(density);
  // вывод, геометрические фигуры
  for (List<String> value : brightness.values()) System.out.print(value.get(0));
  // ◙◘■▩●▦▣◚◛◕▨▧◉▤◐◒▮◍◑▼▪◤▬◗◭◖◈◎◮◊◫▰◄◯□▯▷▫▽◹△◁▸▭◅▵◌▱▹▿◠◃◦◟◞◜
}

/**
 * @param density карта плотности символов
 * @return карта яркости пикселей [0, 255] на основе процента плотности символов
 */
static TreeMap<Integer, List<String>> getBrightnessMap(
        TreeMap<Integer, List<String>> density) {
  int max = density.lastKey(); // максимальная плотность
  TreeMap<Integer, List<String>> brightness = new TreeMap<>();
  for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<String>> entry : density.entrySet()) {
    // яркость пикселя на основе процента плотности символа
    int key = (int) Math.round(255.0 - entry.getKey() * 255.0 / max);
    List<String> value = entry.getValue();
    List<String> val = brightness.remove(key);
    if (val == null) val = new ArrayList<>();
    val.addAll(value);
    brightness.put(key, val);
  }
  return brightness;
}

/**
 * @param f   шрифт для отображения текста
 * @param min диапазон символов, нижняя граница
 * @param max диапазон символов, верхняя граница
 * @param pd  отступ для предосторожности, в большинстве случаев 0
 * @return карта плотности символов: key - плотность, value - список символов
 */
static TreeMap<Integer, List<String>> getDensityMap(
        Font f, int min, int max, int pd) {
  // key - плотность, value - список символов
  TreeMap<Integer, List<String>> density = new TreeMap<>();
  for (int i = min; i <= max; i++) {
    // печатные символы
    if (f.canDisplay(i) && Character.isDefined(i)
          && !Character.isISOControl(i)
          && !Character.isIdentifierIgnorable(i)) {
      String str = String.valueOf(Character.toChars(i));
      int key = getDensity(str, f, pd);
      List<String> list = density.remove(key);
      if (list == null) list = new ArrayList<>();
      list.add(str);
      density.put(key, list);
    }
  }
  return density;
}

/**
 * @param text исходная строка для отрисовки
 * @param f    шрифт для отображения текста
 * @param pd   отступ для предосторожности, в большинстве случаев 0
 * @return плотность символов в этом тексте
 */
static int getDensity(String text, Font f, int pd) {
  FontRenderContext ctx = new FontRenderContext(f.getTransform(), false, false);
  Rectangle bounds = f.getStringBounds(text, ctx).getBounds();
  int width = bounds.width + pd * 2;
  int height = bounds.height + pd * 2;
  BufferedImage image =
          new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY);
  Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
  graphics.setFont(f);
  graphics.drawString(text, pd + bounds.x, pd - bounds.y);
  //ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("text.png"));
  int density = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
      if (image.getRGB(j, i) == 0xFFFFFFFF)
        density++;
  return density;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Полагаю, проще всего отрисовать каждый символ выбранным шрифтом на белый прямоугольник
(собственно говоря - растеризовать его), и посчитать количество черных пикселов. Кроме этого, ввиду всякого там сглаживания будут и серые значения, так что можно их учесть с соответствующим весом.

Получив веса символов,  сортируем их параллельно с самими символами,  и получаем таблицу типа [(0,пробел), (1, ".")...(43, "@")] - пусть, например, `Len=32` элемента.

Не учитывая нелинейность, при рисовании просто отображаем интенсивности пикселов на диапазон длины таблицы, и берём символ с соответствующим индексом

```
print(table[brightness[i][j] * Len / 255] [1])
```

Собственно, эта часть у вас сделана похожим образом.

Если нелинейность слишком велика, то лучше обсчитать все печатные ASCII-символы, и уже из них сделать более-менее равномерную выборку.

Answer (score 1):

### Создаём изображение в стиле ASCII-art, упрощённый вариант

- Допустим, что шкала плотности символов известна и что символы распределены равномерно.
- Допустим, что один символ занимает пространство `21×8` пикселей.

Тогда сначала нужно уменьшить исходное изображение и получить *среднее* значение цвета для занимаемого пространства, потом получить *среднее* значение яркости для этого цвета и затем получить символ соответствующей плотности для этой яркости.

Исходное изображение:

[image: Исходное изображение]

Изображение в стиле ASCII-art:

[image: Изображение в стиле ASCII-art]

---

Этот код читает изображение из файла, уменьшает его в пропорциях: `1/21` высоты и `1/8` ширины, вычисляет *среднее* значение цвета для занимаемого пространства, вычисляет среднее значение яркости для этого цвета, получает символ соответствующей плотности для этой яркости и затем сохраняет эти символы в текстовый файл.

Без масштабирования `scH=1` и `scW=1` количество символов равно количеству пикселей в исходном изображении.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  // допустим, что один символ занимает пространство 21×8 пикселей
  char[][] chars = readImage("/tmp/image.jpg", 21, 8);
  writeToFile("/tmp/image.txt", chars);
}

static char[][] readImage(String path, int scH, int scW) throws IOException {
  BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
  int height = image.getHeight() / scH;
  int width = image.getWidth() / scW;
  char[][] chars = new char[height][width];
  for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
      // масштабируем изображение и складываем цвета
      int colorRGB = 0;
      for (int k = 0; k < scH; k++)
        for (int p = 0; p < scW; p++)
          colorRGB += image.getRGB(j * scW + p, i * scH + k);
      // получаем среднее значение цвета
      Color color = new Color(colorRGB / (scH * scW));
      // складываем R+G+B значения цвета и считаем среднюю яркость
      int brightness = (color.getRed() + color.getGreen() + color.getBlue()) / 3;
      // получаем символ по значению яркости
      chars[i][j] = getDensity(brightness);
    }
  }
  return chars;
}

static final String DENSITY =
      "@QB#NgWM8RDHdOKq9$6khEPXwmeZaoS2yjufF]}{tx1zv7lciL/\\|?*>r^;:_\"~,'.-`";

static char getDensity(int value) {
  // поскольку количество символов меньше 255, будем использовать проценты
  int charValue = (int) Math.round(DENSITY.length() / 255.0 * value);
  charValue = Math.max(charValue, 0);
  charValue = Math.min(charValue, DENSITY.length() - 1);
  return DENSITY.charAt(charValue);
}

static void writeToFile(String path, char[][] chars) throws IOException {
  FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(path);
  for (char[] row : chars) {
    String str = String.valueOf(row);
    writer.append(str).write("\n");
    System.out.println(str); // вывод
  }
  writer.flush();
  writer.close();
}
```

Вывод:

``````````````````````````````
***************************************
***************************************
*************o/xiz|{,/1ctx*************
************77L*```````*_1{j***********
**********?i```````````````FZ**********
**********l`````````````````7**********
**********x`````````````````L**********
**********m?i`````````````iz1**********
************]x```````````\x{***********
********?1w]c>```````````La{]}r********
******jSF~```````````````````^xv>******
*****l1,```````````````````````*Sj*****
****7t```````````````````````````v7****
***uL`````````````````````````````t]***
``````````````````````````````